# How to update data from DataGridView to database? ERROR - Cannot insert value NULL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I'm trying to update data from `DataGridView` to my database. While I was looking for the solution of this problem on google, I noticed that all of the solutions are managed by using class variables (for `DataTable`,`SqlDataAdapter`,...). I'm trying to do this just by using function variables.

This is how I loaded data to `DataGridView`:

```
private void LoadDataGridView(int ID)
{
    try
    {
         SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SENTENCE FROM Sentences WHERE CategoryID = @ID",connection);
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
         DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

         SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

         DataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("ERROR WHILE CONNECTING TO DATABASE!");
    }
}
```

`DataGridView` is showing just those sentences that match particular ID.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
          SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SENTENCE FROM Sentences WHERE CategoryID IN(@CategoryID)", connection);
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = CategoryID;

          SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
          dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
          MessageBox.Show("ERROR WHILE CONNECTING WITH DATABASE!");
    }
}
```

This is the error that comes up:

> Cannot insert value NULL into column CategoryID, table ...;column does not allow nulls.Insert fails. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: so, error say : Your variable `CategoryID` is null. From where You get that, `CategoryID`, variable value?

Comment: I got it from the User. More explanation: DataGridView is showing only column with sentences, not the column with CategoryID. I need to set CategoryID of each sentence that user inputs to a certain value (which, as I said, I previously got from the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION of my problem**:
Firstly, I have shown all columns of database table in `DataGridView` and then I have hided `Primary Key` column and `CategoryID` column. That is shown in the following code:

```
private void LoadDataGridView(int ID)
{
    try
    {
         SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Sentences WHERE CategoryID = @ID";
         cmd.Connection = connection;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;

         dataTable = new DataTable();

         SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

         dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
         dataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
         dataGridView.Columns[2].Visible = false;
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
         MessageBox.Show("ERROR WHILE CONNECTING WITH DATABASE!");
   }
}
```

Then, I have set default value only for `CategoryID` column, because `Primary Key` column has an option of `Auto - Increment`. That is show in the following code:

```
private void dataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["CategoryID"].Value = CategoryID;
}
```

The last thing I have done is implement the code for `RefreshBtn` (the following code is practically the same as the code in question):

```
private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID";
         cmd.Connection = connection;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CategoryID;

         SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
         dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("ERROR WHILE CONNECTING WITH DATABASE !");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your Id data type is int ,you don't need put it inside "".

```
        private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connString;//WHAT EVER IT IS
            string Query=string.Format(@"SELECT QUESTION FROM Questions WHERE CategoryID = '{0}'",CategoryID);
              SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);
              SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
    connection.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd,connString);

              DataTable DataTable=new DataTable();
             dataAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
             datagridview1.DataSource=DataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
              MessageBox.Show("ERROR WHILE CONNECTING WITH DATABASE!");
        }
        catch   (SqlException)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("SqL Error!");

        }
    }
```

Comment: When I use your code, there is no error, but also there is no result.

Comment: Of course there is no result because variable `CategoryID` has no value, it's null. -1

Comment: yes just make sure your  CategoryID get value by some textbox.

Comment: I already have value of CategoryID. Additional explanation: dataGridView contains just one column - sentences while my database contains three columns - primary key(AUTO - INCREMENT), sentences and CategoryID column.